# My Application is not exiting when I double tap the Hardware Back Button

Tags: android, exit, back-button, onbackpressed

I'm trying to exit my application when the user double taps the HardWare Back Button, I've used the following code in my application:

```
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Dashboard_Activity.this.finish();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Here when the user Double Taps the Hardware Back Button the same activity appears again and again, but the app doesn't exits. Can you please help me fixing the issue.

Comment: Hello, did you try to add this to your activity?

Dashboard_Activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: 2 questions : first why you put this super.onBackPressed(); , verify the activity instance, if the activity has multiple instance or not

Comment: is ther any other activity before this Dashboard_Activity ?

Comment: Are you doing something in onFinish() or onDestroy()?

Comment: you have need only single backpressed use onBackpressed{ finish();}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private static long back_pressed;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
        else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

[Source](http://www.androidsnippets.com/double-back-press-to-exit)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method Any where in your code Out side of Oncreate, Working for me

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() 
        {
            try
            {

            //pop up Window closed. 
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }

            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
                }
            }, 2000);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create *SplashScreenActivity*:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finish();
}
```

Then in your activity(or in BaseActivity) add this variable as class member:

```
private long milis;
```

And override *onBackPressed():*

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(milis + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```